# Data Warehouse and Django

Tags: django, postgresql, data-warehouse

This is more of an architectural question than a technological one per se.

I am currently building a business website/social network that needs to store large volumes of data and use that data to draw analytics (consumer behavior).

I am using Django and a PostgreSQL database.

Now my question is: I want to expand this architecture to include a data warehouse. The ideal would be: the operational DB would be the current Django PostgreSQL database, and the data warehouse would be something additional, preferably in a multidimensional model.

We are still in a very early phase, we are going to test with 50 users, so something primitive such as a one-column table for starters would be enough.

I would like to know if somebody has experience in this situation, and that could recommend me a framework to create a data warehouse, all while mantaining the operational DB with the Django models for ease of use (if possible).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What about replication to your datawarehouse?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some cool Open Source tools I used recently:

- [Kettle](http://kettle.pentaho.com/) - great ETL tool, you can use this to extract the data from your operational database into your warehouse. Supports any database with a JDBC driver and makes it very easy to build e.g. a star schema.
- [Saiku](http://analytical-labs.com/) - nice Web 2.0 frontend built on [Pentaho Mondrian](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/) (MDX implementation). This allows your users to easily build complex aggregation queries (think Pivot table in Excel), and the Mondrian layer provides caching etc. to make things go fast. Try [the demo](http://demo.analytical-labs.com/) here.

Comment: Thank you, these are very very good candidates. This is probably along the line of what I need.

Comment: +1. Hi Ramseyer, I have develop a few OLAP projects with SSAS + Tableau Software. For a non profit oranization I will start a new project with Mondrian + Saiku. I can send my e-mail address with you if you want to share your expertice with me. Only to know what to take in mind before switch to this environment.

Answer (score 0):

My answer does not necessarily apply to data warehousing. In your case I see the possibility to implement a [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) database solution alongside an OLTP relational storage, which in this case is PostgreSQL.

Why consider *NoSQL*? In addition to the obvious scalability benefits, NoSQL offer a number of advantages that *probably* will apply to your scenario. For instance, the flexibility of having records with different sets of fields, and key-based access.

Since you're still in "trial" stage you might find it easier to decide for a NoSQL database solution depending on your hosting provider. For instance [AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/) have [SimpleDB](http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/), [Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/) provide their own [DataStore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/), etc. However there are plenty of other NoSQL solutions you can go for that have nice Python bindings.

Comment: The scalability benefits are not obvious to me.  One social site was considering doing what you describe and benchmarked the products they were considering.  See the presentation of their results here: http://www.pgcon.org/2010/schedule/attachments/141_PostgreSQL-and-NoSQL.pdf  Pages 33 and 34 have the graphs of time by product (shorter bars mean better performance).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, considering I'll need to do very complex queries that include aggregations, a system that supports OLAP instead of a OLTP one would be preferred, correct ?